# Class exist in two location

Tags: c#, asp.net

In my asp.net application i am getting following error.

```
CS0433: The type 'CalendarEvent' exists in both    
'c:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727\Temporary ASP.NET 
Files\root\55ab4ea2\d39b7005\assembly\dl3\9c91cbe9\ab39aebd_e9f8cf01\SchoolPlus.DLL' and 
'c:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727\Temporary ASP.NET 
 Files\root\55ab4ea2\d39b7005\App_Code.llm6xiuo.dll'
```

Why i am getting this?

I have deleted all specified path in error.

[image]

Comment: Check your references, do you have a reference to the output of the project, ie. a reference to itself?

Comment: seem like the class is defined in 2 places: in SchoolPlus.dll and in App_Code folder, please verify to make sure only one exists

Answer (score 0):

Happens to me sometimes too, try cleaning and then building the solution.

> Right click [solution] > 'Clean' > 'Build'

Or just:

> Right click [solution] > 'Rebuild'

Which cleans + builds in one go.

This will clear the output directories and regenerate fresh copies of the .dlls

Comment: he may also need clean up (delete content) c:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727\Temporary ASP.NET 
Files\